# How to call a property from ASP.NET web form file

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to populate the value of input field with value from property. How can I do that besides setting in the code behind file?

```
<%@ Import Namespace="PCF.Entities.Models" %>

<input id="firstName" type="text" value="<%  %>" size="26"  maxlength="15"   name="firstName" tabindex="2" runat="server" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: Which property is that? Where is it declared?

Comment: In code behind file var emp = LoaRepository.GetLOAById(id);

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { var emp = LoaRepository.GetLOAById(id); }

Comment: This is not a property, this is a local variable. You can only use that inside the method it was declared, that is in Page_Load. See the answer by Win below, I was about to suggest the same. Just bear in mind that this approach won't work with Page_load, you should initialize property earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use <%= %>

### ASPX

```
<%= Name %>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected string Name
{
    get { return "John Doe"; }
}
```

However, in your scenario. You should be using [ASP.Net Textbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control.

### ASPX

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="FirstNameTextBox"
        MaxLength="15" Enabled="False" />
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FirstNameTextBox.Text = "John Doe";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make your input field `runat="server"` and you will get the access of input at code behind file.